# creating hooks in python twisted

Tags: python, hook, twisted, decorator

i am using twisted to make a simple server . i have several resources (endpoints) to which i can make a http call. i need to add hooks like in `falcon` or `flask` to get query parameters for every call . how can i achieve that .

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource, NoResource
import json
import redis
from twisted.internet import threads, defer
from twisted.web.server import NOT_DONE_YET
import time

class JobListener(Resource):

    isLeaf = True

    def render_POST(self, request):
        # i want query params here
        return NOT_DONE_YET


class Home(Resource):

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        uri =  request.uri
        print uri
        if uri == '/':
            return self
        if uri == '/api/v1/dump':
            return JobListener()
        else:
            return NoResource()

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html><body>Welcome to the server!</body></html>"
```

whenever i hit `/api/v1/dump` it calls JobListener i want somehow to have add a hook to all endpoints that populates the query params when an api is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query arguments are available on the request object.  See `args` on:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.iweb.IRequest.html

Comment: I'm not sure, it wasn't me.  Perhaps someone thought it was too simple a question, easily answered by the docs, or perhaps someone thought it was difficult to understand as asked (ie, because `Home` seems like unnecessary complexity to the question which is just about accessing query args).  Just guessing, though.

Comment: i already knew abt `request.args` but i was looking for some answer like `falcon` or `flask` hooks . i accepted your answer because it makes sense and i think this is the only way in twisted. i hope people who simply down-vote should read the question atleast

Comment: A better way to ask what you're trying to ask, I suppose, would be to give an inline example of how you'd do what you want with falcon or flask.  As written, it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve (or maybe it is for someone with a ton of flask or falcon experience).

Comment: .i get the point now .question should have been phrased correctly with some example i would make changes to it